# Youtube Data API - search should match all keywords

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api, keyword-search

I'm using the Youtube Data API to search for videos from stage rallying events (auto racing).
The problem is that a lot of the search results don't match all of my keywords. **Is there a way to force the API to only return videos that match all of the provided key words?**

Here is an example...searching for onboard videos of Rally San Marino 2015:

```
Rally San Marino 2015 camera|onboard -legend
```

Notes:

1) There is a different event named "San Marino Rally Legend" which I'm not interested in, therefore I'm excluding all videos from that event using the "-legend" keyword.

2) Italians often use the keyword "Camera Car" in the description/title of onboard videos, therefore I'm searching for camera.

My expectations now would be that it only returns videos which description OR title OR tags contains the following keywords in what ever order: `"Rally" AND "San" AND "Marino" AND "2015" AND ("camera" OR "onboard") AND NOT "legend"`

However the API returns a lot of videos which do not match that scheme.
The first one is a match:

```
"43° SAN MARINO RALLY - Camera Car Chardonnet Shakedown - 12/07/2015"|CObJBEALs3Y
```

But all others do not match:

1) `Camera|Onboard` didn't match:

```
"43° rally san marino 2015 - Hightlights only gravel...pure sound (HD)"|_nO-BOT9TWQ
```

2) `Camera|Onboard` didn't match:

```
"Test Andreucci-Andreussi - Rally San Marino 2015"|6AXSUEXLTuY
description: "Test Andreucci-Andreussi - Pre-Rally San Marino 2015 - Peugeot 208 R5."
```

3) `San Marino 2015` didn't match:

```
"IRC Rally Valli Cuneesi  2016 - Camera Car VINCITORI ASSOLUTI (Chentre - Florean"
description: "Rally Valli Cuneesi 2016 - Camera Car VINCITORI ASSOLUTI (Chentre - Florean) - Rally Video - Camera Car On-board Facebook ..."
```

Here is the URL that I'm using:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&key=YOUR-API-KEY&type=video&maxResults=15&videoEmbeddable=true&publishedAfter=2015-01-01T00:00:00Z&q=Rally+san+Marino+2015+camera%7Conboard%20-legend
```

Comment: Consider add more filters like: `order:viewCount` or `order:videoCount` or any of these [parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?hl=en#parameters): `videoCategoryId`, `videoDuration`, `relatedToVideoId`. Please test with any of these additional filters and update your question.

Comment: Hi Marco, thanks for your comment. Sorry but I don't see how ordering by viewCount, videoCount or videoDuration would solve my problem. The irrelevant videos are in the same category as the relevant videos, so videoCategory will not help either. In the meantime what I ended up doing was, looping through the results list and programmatically removing all irrelevant videos that do not match all of the keywords. Fun though is that it often finds a couple of videos on the first result page, then none on pages 2 and 3 and then again 5 videos on the 4th page.

Comment: by filtering with other parameters, the search will be more "precise", also, you can add hashtags of another keywords found in the description of those videos in the search or use `relatedvideoid` parameter value for find related videos to one you consider match with your requirements.